# scaling equation within margin

Tags: formatting, scaling

I have split an equation across several lines but I couldn't remain perfectly within the margin.

[image]

The input is

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    & \ddot\phi_3+\phi_3+sin(\tau+\alpha)[p_1\Delta \alpha+2 \nabla p_1 \nabla \alpha] \\
    & \qquad -\cos(\tau+ \alpha)[\Delta p_1 -p_1 (\nabla \alpha)^2+\frac{5}{6}g_2^2p_1^3- \frac{3}{4}g_3p_1^3-p_1 +\omega_2 p_1]
    +\frac{ p_1^3}{12}(2g_2^2+3g_3)\cos3(\tau + \alpha) \\
    & \qquad +g_2 p_1 [p_2+ p_2 cos2(\tau +\alpha)+q_2 \sin2(\tau+\alpha)] =0
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}\label{eq10}
\begin{split}
& \ddot\phi_3+\phi_3+\sin(\tau+\alpha)[p_1\Delta \alpha+2 \nabla p_1 \nabla \alpha] \\
& \qquad  -\cos(\tau+ \alpha)[\Delta p_1-p_1 (\nabla \alpha)^2 + \lambda p_1^3-p_1+\omega_2 p_1] +\frac{p_1^3}{12}(2g_2^2+3g_3)\cos3(\tau + \alpha) \\
 & \qquad +g_2 p_1 [p_2+ p_2 \cos2(\tau +\alpha)+q_2 \sin2(\tau+\alpha)]=0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Add some more ``\\`` in the `split` environments where needed...

Comment: Can you just do one then I will be able to follow that.

Comment: Just add `\\ & ` somewhere. That will do another split. E.g. `\\ & \qquad +\frac{ p_1^3}{12}(2g_2^2+3g_3)\cos3(\tau + \alpha) \\ `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can this one be OK for you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\begin{aligned}
    \ddot\phi_3&+\phi_3+\sin(\tau+\alpha)[p_1\Delta \alpha+2 \nabla p_1 \nabla \alpha] \\
    & -\cos(\tau+ \alpha)\left[\Delta p_1 -p_1 (\nabla \alpha)^2+\frac{5}{6}g_2^2p_1^3- \frac{3}{4}g_3p_1^3-p_1 +\omega_2 p_1\right] \\
    & +\frac{ p_1^3}{12}(2g_2^2+3g_3)\cos3(\tau + \alpha) \\
    & +g_2 p_1 [p_2+ p_2 \cos2(\tau +\alpha)+q_2 \sin2(\tau+\alpha)] =0
\end{aligned}\nonumber\\[15pt]
&\begin{aligned}\label{eq10}
    \ddot\phi_3&+\phi_3+\sin(\tau+\alpha)[p_1\Delta \alpha+2 \nabla p_1 \nabla \alpha] \\
    & -\cos(\tau+ \alpha)[\Delta p_1-p_1 (\nabla \alpha)^2 + \lambda p_1^3-p_1+\omega_2 p_1] \\
    & +\frac{p_1^3}{12}(2g_2^2+3g_3)\cos3(\tau + \alpha) \\
    & +g_2 p_1 [p_2+ p_2 \cos2(\tau +\alpha)+q_2 \sin2(\tau+\alpha)]=0
\end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. Since the two equations are consecutive, probably this way looks better than the one with `equation` and `split`.

Comment: You just added  \\ ?

Comment: No, I don't... Since I made an answer, I've tried to make it a bit better looking (IMHO).

Comment: actually I have to do lots of equation in the following manner you did. Can you tell me little bit what have you added then it will be easy for me. 
Thanks

Comment: I've used only one `align` for the two equations, each one inside an `aligned` environment so they can be aligned together.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{align}
    &\begin{aligned}
    & \ddot\phi_3+\phi_3+sin(\tau+\alpha)[p_1\Delta \alpha+2 \nabla p_1 \nabla \alpha] \        & \qquad -\cos(\tau+ \alpha)[\Delta p_1 -p_1 (\nabla \alpha)^2+\frac{5}{6}g_2^2p_1^3- \frac{3}{4}g_3p_1^3-p_1 +\omega_2 p_1]
        +\frac{ p_1^3}{12}(2g_2^2+3g_3)\cos3(\tau + \alpha) \        & \qquad +g_2 p_1 [p_2+ p_2 cos2(\tau +\alpha)+q_2 \sin2(\tau+\alpha)] =0
    \end{aligned}
    \end{align}
    
    \end{document}

Comment: As you have said I did like this but  it  doesn't look like your style

Comment: I also used as you said \begin{align} then \aligned but look different than yours.

Comment: Why don't you copy the code in my answer into a blank document and analyse it? I've added ``\\`` after the second right bracket, but I've also changed many more things.

Comment: I have tried according to you your suggestion, can you see please? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130038/equation-formatting-alinging

Comment: Don't forget to use `\!` before `aligned`, `gathered` and `multlined` because there is a `\,` added by Michael Spivak by default.